# ItemView.setOnCLickListiner is Being Ignored and does not get clicked when it is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-viewholder

please can anyone help me fix this my itemview is not being clicked wen i click it in my  fragment  after implementing my onItemClickListener interface in my adapter, i also called the adapter in my fragment but if i run the app and i click d cardview nothing happens and am using list adapter which extends recyclerView. please if anyone can help me i will b grateful

**my adapter**

```
public  class Apiary_Adapter extends ListAdapter<RecordModel,Apiary_Adapter.ApiaryHolder> {
    Apiaries apiaries;
    Context context;
    RecordOnClickListener listener;
    public RecordViewModel record_View_model = Apiaries.record_View_model;


    public Apiary_Adapter(Apiaries apiaries, Context context ) {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.apiaries = apiaries;
        this.context = context;

    }




    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecordModel> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecordModel>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull RecordModel oldItem, @NonNull RecordModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull RecordModel oldItem, @NonNull RecordModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.getAddress().equals(newItem.getAddress())&&oldItem.getApiaryNo().equals(newItem.getApiaryNo())
                    &&oldItem.getTown().equals(newItem.getTown())&&oldItem.getApiaryLongitude().equals(newItem.getApiaryLongitude())
                    &&oldItem.getApiaryLatitude().equals(newItem.getApiaryLatitude())&&oldItem.getDateOfHarvest().equals(newItem.getDateOfHarvest())
                    &&oldItem.getDateOfColonisation().equals(newItem.getDateOfColonisation())&&oldItem.getNoOfWaxHarvested().equals(newItem.getNoOfWaxHarvested())
                    &&oldItem.getQuantityOfHoneyHarvested().equals(newItem.getQuantityOfHoneyHarvested())&&oldItem.getNoOfPropolis().equals(newItem.getNoOfPropolis())
                    &&oldItem.getNoOfCombs().equals(newItem.getNoOfCombs())&&oldItem.getHiveNo().equals(newItem.getHiveNo())
                    &&oldItem.getHiveLongitude().equals(newItem.getHiveLongitude())&&oldItem.getHiveLatitude().equals(newItem.getHiveLatitude())
                    &&oldItem.getTime().equals(newItem.getTime())&&oldItem.getDate().equals(newItem.getDate());
        }
    };

    public class ApiaryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView address;
        private TextView apiary;
        private   TextView town;
        private   TextView LocationLatitude;
        private   TextView LocationLongitude;
        private   TextView HiveLatitude;
        private   TextView HiveLongitude;
        private   TextView date;
        private   TextView time;
        private TextView hiveNo;
        private TextView noOfComb;
        private TextView dateOfHarvest;
        private TextView dateOfColonisation;
        private TextView waxHarvested;
        private TextView quantityOfhoney;
        private TextView noOfPropolis;
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        CardView cardView;
        Apiaries apiaries;


        public ApiaryHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Apiaries apiaries) {
            super(itemView);


            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customAddress);
            apiary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customApiaryNo);
            town = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customTown);
            LocationLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customLongitude);
            LocationLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customLatitude);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCheckbox);
            hiveNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customHiveNo);
            noOfComb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCombNo);
            dateOfHarvest = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customDateOfHarvest);
            dateOfColonisation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customDateOfColonisation);
            waxHarvested = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customNoOfWaxHarveted);
            quantityOfhoney = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customQuantityOfHoney);
            noOfPropolis = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customNoOfPropolis);
            HiveLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customHiveLatitude);
            HiveLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customHiveLongitude);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customDate);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customTime);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Cardview);
            this.apiaries = apiaries;
            mainActivity = new MainActivity();
            cardView.setOnLongClickListener(apiaries);



            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int Position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (listener != null && Position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.OnItemClick(getItem(Position));
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Hello9", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ApiaryHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customlayout, parent, false);
        final ApiaryHolder apiaryHolder= new ApiaryHolder(itemView, apiaries);

        return apiaryHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ApiaryHolder holder, final int position) {
        RecordModel currentRecord = getItem(position);
        holder.address.setText(currentRecord.getAddress());
        holder.apiary.setText(currentRecord.getApiaryNo());
        holder.town.setText(currentRecord.getTown());
        holder.LocationLatitude.setText(currentRecord.getApiaryLatitude());
        holder.LocationLongitude.setText(currentRecord.getApiaryLongitude());
        holder.hiveNo.setText(currentRecord.getHiveNo());
        holder.noOfComb.setText(currentRecord.getNoOfCombs());
        holder.dateOfHarvest.setText(currentRecord.getDateOfHarvest());
        holder.dateOfColonisation.setText(currentRecord.getDateOfColonisation());
        holder.waxHarvested.setText(currentRecord.getNoOfWaxHarvested());
        holder.quantityOfhoney.setText(currentRecord.getQuantityOfHoneyHarvested());
        holder.noOfPropolis.setText(currentRecord.getNoOfPropolis());
        holder.HiveLatitude.setText(currentRecord.getHiveLatitude());
        holder.HiveLongitude.setText(currentRecord.getHiveLongitude());
        holder.date.setText(currentRecord.getDate());
        holder.time.setText(currentRecord.getTime());

    }

    public  interface  RecordOnClickListener{
        void OnItemClick(RecordModel recordModel);

    }

    public  void setOnItemClickListener(RecordOnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

**my fragment**

```
public class Apiaries extends Fragment implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    public static boolean is_in_contextualMode = false;
    public static RecordViewModel record_View_model;
    Apiary_Adapter  apiary_adapter;
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static ArrayList<RecordModel> selectionList =new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static SearchView searchView;
    public static final int ADD_RECORD_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int EDIT_RECORD_REQUEST = 2;
    com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    public  static MainActivity mainActivity;
    private  Menu menu;
    ArrayList<RecordModel> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public Apiaries() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_apiaries, container, false);

        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        Apiaries apiaries = new Apiaries();
        apiary_adapter = new Apiary_Adapter(apiaries, getActivity());

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUserId);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(apiary_adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity =  new MainActivity();

        record_View_model = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(RecordViewModel.class);
        record_View_model.getAllRecord().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<RecordModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<RecordModel> recordModels) {
               apiary_adapter.submitList(recordModels);
            }
        });


        apiary_adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Apiary_Adapter.RecordOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(RecordModel recordModel) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditApiaryAddActivity.class);
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_ID, recordModel.getId());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, recordModel.getAddress());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_APIARYNAME, recordModel.getApiaryNo());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_TOWN, recordModel.getTown());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_LOCATION_LATITUDE, recordModel.getApiaryLatitude());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, recordModel.getApiaryLongitude());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_HIVE_LATITUDE, recordModel.getHiveLatitude());
                intent .putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_HIVE_LONGITUDE, recordModel.getHiveLongitude());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_HIVENO, recordModel.getHiveNo());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_NOOFCOMBS, recordModel.getNoOfCombs());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_DATEOFHARVEST, recordModel.getNoOfWaxHarvested());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_DATEOFCOLONISATION, recordModel.getDateOfColonisation());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_WAXHARVESTED, recordModel.getNoOfWaxHarvested());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_QUANTITYOFHONEY, recordModel.getQuantityOfHoneyHarvested());
                intent.putExtra(EditApiaryAddActivity.EXTRA_NOOFPROPOLIS, recordModel.getNoOfPropolis());
                startActivityForResult(intent,EDIT_RECORD_REQUEST);
                Apiaries.is_in_contextualMode = false;
                mainActivity.clearActionMode();
            }
        });




    }



   
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        MainActivity.toolbar.getMenu().clear();
        MainActivity.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_record);
        MainActivity.textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MainActivity.itemCountTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        is_in_contextualMode = true;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle Clicks in the  `onCreateViewHolder` method

```
        public ApiaryHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.customlayout, parent, false);
            final ApiaryHolder apiaryHolder= new ApiaryHolder(itemView, apiaries);
            
             ApiaryHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //handle the clicks here
                }
            }
        });
    
            return apiaryHolder;
        }
```

Comment: i can not get adapters position in the onCreteViewHolder

Comment: yes you  can    final int position = apiaryHolder.getAdapterPosition();

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `onLongClickListener` Instead of `onClickListener`

Comment: the `OnlongClicklistener` is performing   another function

Answer (score 0):

Add the `onClickListener` Inside on `bindviewholder` Like `holder.itemView.setOnClickLstener`